# How to setup Cargo project along side a Python virtual environment?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have an existing Python project which I want to add some Rust components to because some of those existing components cannot be implemented in Python. (It's just not fast enough to implement the required algorithm.)

My existing project structure looks like this:

```
my_project/
  .venv/
  bin/
    # Python executables
  src/
    # Python libraries
  pyproject.toml
  activate -> .venv/bin/activate
```

Since all of the stuff under `my_project` is all related to Python it probably makes a lot of sense to create a Python folder, and move all of the existing code.

```
my_project/
  python/
    .venv/
    bin/
      # Python executables
    src/
      # Python libraries
    pyproject.toml
    activate -> .venv/bin/activate
```

It would then make sense to add a `rust` folder.

```
my_project/
  python/
    .venv/
    bin/
      # Python executables
    src/
      # Python libraries
    pyproject.toml
    activate -> .venv/bin/activate
  rust/
    Cargo.toml
```

If you don't agree with these assumptions please do say so.

The problem with this appears to be that the VS-Code Rust Analyzer extension expects the Cargo.toml file to be in the root directory. Which suggests it can't be under a `rust` folder.

Is there a way to tell Cargo about the existence of a recursive project structure?

The file `rust/Cargo.toml` should probably define the `[workspace]` members.

It appears to be the case that I can move the `Cargo.toml` file to the root, and then modify it like this:

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "rust/rust_test",
    "rust/rust_test_2",
]
```

Is that the only option? I'm not sure this will work when it comes to creating a Rust library under the folder `rust`.

Any suggestions as to possible options?

Answer (score 0):

rust-analyzer can recognize non-root Cargo.toml, it just needs a little configuration.

Set the setting `rust-analyzer.linkedProjects` to an array of paths to Cargo.toml files (in VSCode you can do that in the project's settings.json).

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, can you possibly explain in a little more detail?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Put .vscode/settings.json with `{ "rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": ["paths/to", "cargo/tomls"] }` (assuming VSCode).